# MDI Child form close on new open

Tags: vb.net

How to close MDI Chid form when i want to open a new one.

On this way i open both of them but i want to close the previous when opening the new one.

```
 Private Sub DostupniToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DostupniToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim frm As New FrmDostupniZaposlenici
        frm.MdiParent = Me
        frm.Show()
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End Sub

Private Sub DodajToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DodajToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim frm As New frmDodajZaposlenika
    frm.MdiParent = Me
    frm.Show()
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub
```

I have around 10 mdi child forms.

Edit :

New code. How to prevent to open form on form. Example i want to close all other mdi forms when new form is open. 
On this way if i click on 4 buttons in toolstrip i got 4 forms opened. I don't want that. If i click on button 3 i want to close the previous form and load the form3.

```
    Private Sub DostupniToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DostupniToolStripMenuItem.Click
    FrmDostupniZaposlenici.MdiParent = Me
    FrmDostupniZaposlenici.Show()
    FrmDostupniZaposlenici.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub

Private Sub DodajToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DodajToolStripMenuItem.Click
    frmDodajZaposlenika.MdiParent = Me
    frmDodajZaposlenika.Show()
    frmDodajZaposlenika.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub

Private Sub IzmjeniToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles IzmjeniToolStripMenuItem.Click
    frmIzmjenaZaposlenika.MdiParent = Me
    frmIzmjenaZaposlenika.Show()
    frmIzmjenaZaposlenika.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub

Private Sub ObrisiToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ObrisiToolStripMenuItem.Click
    frmObrisiZaposlenika.MdiParent = Me
    frmObrisiZaposlenika.Show()
    frmObrisiZaposlenika.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub
```

Comment: There's not much point in using MDI if you only ever want a single maximized child.  Use the MdiChildren property to find active child windows.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure i understood what are you trying to say. You think i can use this without going as MDI Child forms ? All i want when opening new MDI form ( example click on Dodaj it will close all other forms and then open the new MDI form " )

Comment: That was clear, what is not clear is why you have trouble using the MdiChildren property.  Update your snippet so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me but unfortunately i don't understand what are you trying to say. I added the full code. Is there any function to close all MDIChild forms at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop through all the open MDI child forms and close them ...

```
For Each f As Form In Me.MdiChildren
     f.Close()
Next
```

Comment: As mentioned below, `.Close()` disposes of the current MDIChildren. Meaning you can't open one of the closed forms again, you can't. Solve this by using `.Hide()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To close an opened child form first, enter the following codes in the click event of the menu item, just immediately after declaring the child form.

`ActiveMdiChild.Close()`

Comment: For the record, this seems to dispose of the MDI child form, meaning if you want to open it again, you can't. Solve this by using `.Hide()` instead.